# prevent form submit on enter in magento catalogsearch

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

default magento search work using hit enter key or submit button.but now i need this search work only for pressing submit button and not work for hit enter key.is there any way for this?. I am using magento 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function to disable enter key for search box

Here is code to disable search box

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

If jQuery library not include then please use above code to include jQuery library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#search_mini_form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

jQuery library is required for above code

Comment: answer edited please check

Comment: if jQuery is not include then code will not work put above 2 line line in your code

Comment: sorry this code is not working for catalogsearch

Comment: Is there any error in console

Comment: it works when first time hit enter.after that hit enter it not works.That means first time search not work for enter button but twice we hit enter button search is working

Comment: I tried this and it's working fine. Are you using any kind of autosearch or search related extension

Comment: no.only default magento search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54471/discussion-between-venu-gopal-and-vaibhav-ahalpara).